# is surname often put after title like Prof or Dr? we got the name "Stephen Hawking" and we often heard "Prof Hawking" and not "Prof Stephen"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

let say, we got the name "Stephen Hawking" and we often heard "Prof Hawking" and not "Prof Stephen"?

in Asia, we always use first-name (or given name) after title.

is surname often put after title like Prof or Dr?

Comment: In the West, we don't say, for example, *Teacher Joe* like you guys say in Asia. Here we either use the surname *or* the 'full name' together, after titles. (By 'full name' I mean 'first name' and/or 'middle name' and/or the initials thereof *plus* the surname.)

Comment: In Asia, do you always use the first name or the family name?  I know that, in much of Asia, the first name **is** the family name, while in Europe and the US (and most of the West), the family name is **second**.

Comment: depend on the country, sometimes fname  come first sometimes come last. My question say fname means fname regarding of the order.

Comment: You might want to use the term "given name" then, to reduce confusion. :) You might also consider mentioning which country you're from because I know that in Japan, for example, it's very uncommon to use given name for anyone you don't know well.

Answer (score 5):

Formally, we use last names (family names) after titles such as Dr. or Prof.:

> Professor Smith and Doctor Jones will attend the conference next week.

Using a first name instead of a last name is unusual. It would be regarded as somewhat playful, and often denotes familiarity. You wouldn't see it in formal writing, but you do sometimes see it with celebrities:

> Most Wednesday mornings, I watch Judge Judy right after Dr. Phil.

<sup>(In the U.S., both [Judge Judy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judge_Judy) and [Dr. Phil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phil_McGraw) are syndicated television programs.)</sup>

I've never heard anyone refer to Stephen Hawking as "Professor Stephen." The only context I could think of where that *might* be appropriate is with one of his graduate students, and, even then, the student would have had to build up a very strong rapport with his esteemed advisor (unless, of course, Dr. Hawking prefers to be on a first-name basis with all of his students). But, in English, that's not the way we normally refer to Nobel laureates and other greats.

I would say that using a title with a first name is akin to using other informal nicknames such as "Doc". In most situations, I'd avoid being the first to use such language; it could be considered impolite depending on the circumstances. However, I've known a few folks who have been uncomfortable with formal titles, and prefer something more informal on a face-to-face basis.

Comment: The only time I can think it's really common (other than on those shows you mentioned) is in daycare classrooms for young children, they will often call their teacher Miss. Anna or Mr. John. It gives them a bit of formality without using family names.

Comment: @Catija - I hadn't thought of that, but you are exactly right.

Comment: Thank JR, they didn't teach this in English textbook in Asia

Comment: And a few holders of old feudal titles are referred to by TITLE+FORENAME: Queen Elizabeth and Prince Andrew, Lord Jack and Lady Jill for younger sons and daughters of peers, Sir Laurence and Dame Edna are all proper.

Comment: Another circumstance where I've seen Dr. + FIRSTNAME is in a medical or dental practice where multiple doctors have the same last name (e.g. brothers, father and son, etc.) The staff will say "Dr. Brian" or "Dr. Mark" to distinguish the two.

Comment: @StoneyB Your Lord example is incorrect: marquesses, earls, viscounts and barons are addressed as either Lord Surname or Lord Territory, e.g., Lord Tennyson (Alfred Tennyson, 1st Baron Tennyson) and Lord Salisbury (Robert Gascoyne-Cecil, 5th Marquess of Salisbury) (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peerage_of_the_United_Kingdom#Titles). Similarly for women, e.g., Lady Thatcher (Margaret Thatcher, Baroness Thatcher).

Comment: I can't imagine anyone within academia in the UK addressing another academic as Dr/Prof Firstname, except perhaps as a joke or nickname. Stephen Hawking would always be "Stephen" or "Professor Hawking", depending on the level of familiarity.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Note that I specified "younger sons and daughters of peers".

Comment: @DavidR - RE: _I can't imagine anyone within academia in the UK addressing another academic as Dr/Prof Firstname, except perhaps as a joke or nickname._ Yes, exactly. Well said. When I started my answer, I began by thinking, "That's simply not practiced," but then I remembered a few exceptions here and there. Another time you might see this is when someone has a particularly vexing last name; that person might say, "Just call me Dr. Ben," although sometimes a last initial is used instead ([Coach K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Krzyzewski) comes to mind).